# Flutter / VSC Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I have a flutter project set up with Git in visual studio code. 
I tried to pull from Git and I guess I got a merge conflict.

Now I get the error "Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK. Please run 'flutter doctor' in the terminal then reload the project once all issues are resolved"

And when run flutter doctor:

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD
b863200c37df4ed378042de11c4e9ff34e4e58c9
=======
2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695
>>>>>>> 27321ebbad34b0a3fafe99fac037102196d655ff...
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD
b863200c37df4ed378042de11c4e9ff34e4e58c9
=======
2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695
>>>>>>> 27321ebbad34b0a3fafe99fac037102196d655ff/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

How can I fix this issue?
Any help is appreciated.

Git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Run
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
in Flutter directory

Output:

```
Juju@Juju-MacBook-Pro flutter % git clean -xfd
Removing .DS_Store
Removing .idea/
Skipping repository .pub-cache/git/goldens-c47f1308188dca65b3899228cac37f252ea8b411
Removing .pub-cache/git/cache
Removing .pub-cache/_temp
Removing .pub-cache/hosted
Removing bin/cache/
Removing dev/automated_tests/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/complex_layout.iml
Removing dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/bots/bots.iml
Removing dev/bots/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/customer_testing/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/devicelab/devicelab.iml
Removing dev/devicelab/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_kitchen_sink/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_load_rotate/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_trans_rotate/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/android_views/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/channels/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/codegen/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/external_ui/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/flavors/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/image_loading/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/ios_add2app/flutterapp/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/named_isolates/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/platform_interaction/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/release_smoke_test/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/simple_codegen/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/ui/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/integration_tests/web/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/manual_tests/android.iml
Removing dev/manual_tests/manual_tests.iml
Removing dev/manual_tests/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/snippets/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/tools/gen_keycodes/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/tools/pubspec.lock
Removing dev/tools/tools.iml
Removing dev/tools/vitool/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/catalog/catalog.iml
Removing examples/catalog/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/flutter_gallery/android.iml
Removing examples/flutter_gallery/flutter_gallery.iml
Removing examples/flutter_gallery/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/flutter_view/flutter_view.iml
Removing examples/flutter_view/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/hello_world/android.iml
Removing examples/hello_world/hello_world.iml
Removing examples/hello_world/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/image_list/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/layers/layers.iml
Removing examples/layers/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/platform_channel/android.iml
Removing examples/platform_channel/platform_channel.iml
Removing examples/platform_channel/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/platform_channel_swift/platform_channel_swift.iml
Removing examples/platform_channel_swift/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/platform_view/android.iml
Removing examples/platform_view/full_platform_view.iml
Removing examples/platform_view/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/stocks/android.iml
Removing examples/stocks/pubspec.lock
Removing examples/stocks/stocks.iml
Removing flutter_root.iml
Removing packages/flutter/coverage/
Removing packages/flutter/flutter.iml
Removing packages/flutter/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_driver/flutter_driver.iml
Removing packages/flutter_driver/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_goldens/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_goldens_client/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.iml
Removing packages/flutter_localizations/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_test/flutter_test.iml
Removing packages/flutter_test/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_test/test/test_config/project_root/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_tools/.dart_tool/
Removing packages/flutter_tools/.packages
Removing packages/flutter_tools/flutter_tools.iml
Removing packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/flutter_tools/test/data/asset_test/main/pubspec.lock
Removing packages/fuchsia_remote_debug_protocol/pubspec.lock
Juju@Juju-MacBook-Pro flutter % git stash save --keep-index
bin/internal/engine.version: needs merge
dev/bots/test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/attach.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/context_runner.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/macos/cocoapods.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/mdns_discovery.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/commands.shard/hermetic/attach_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/ios/devices_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/macos/cocoapods_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/mdns_discovery_test.dart: needs merge
bin/internal/engine.version: needs merge
dev/bots/test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/attach.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/context_runner.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/devices.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/macos/cocoapods.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/mdns_discovery.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/commands.shard/hermetic/attach_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/ios/devices_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/macos/cocoapods_test.dart: needs merge
packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/mdns_discovery_test.dart: needs merge
bin/internal/engine.version: unmerged (9b47683e091e31759027947b50967b113e5c4a0e)
bin/internal/engine.version: unmerged (446391086d1083a9efd4e552d90c763a1a5b0353)
bin/internal/engine.version: unmerged (cf062e01a0c732cce453bb1c83a15816aaef7ffd)
dev/bots/test.dart: unmerged (c546075ce7839a936a31ae5df42c2797ad288645)
dev/bots/test.dart: unmerged (aef335fd140f9054ac355231dd37a71f6505c9d9)
dev/bots/test.dart: unmerged (ee779205405e32b833e783409a50ab1147dc0e1d)
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/attach.dart: unmerged (dd68a476a86d24e8ea787970ad4209fd532cc505)
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/attach.dart: unmerged (20a23a31fa261bcd8ce90a6913b6da8a809875be)
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/attach.dart: unmerged (5c9e24302d0b51e47b95fefbfd19aa5098d2bca3)
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/context_runner.dart: unmerged (83985e5fce6f592ecb4cd1ee4e909aa4ce11740b)
...
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
Juju@Jujus-MacBook-Pro flutter % git stash drop
No stash entries found.
Juju@Jujus-MacBook-Pro flutter % git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Solution

```
git reset head --hard
```

in flutter directory and afterwards

```
flutter doctor
```

in the project worked for me! It reinstalled the flutter sdk automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely just a merge conflict so dont be panic. Run git status and post the result first.

Comment: How about the git status in the flutter sdk project?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? This is when I have my flutter project open in vsc and type in "git status" into the terminal. Sorry I'm a beginner...

Comment: Since there's no conflict in the project, I doubt the merge conflict happens in the flutter sdk folder. Flutter install directory is in an inconsistent state and that causes all kinds of troubles. Go there and take some reset and re pull.
Check this section.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: Did all the commands. Updated the post with the output. How can I fix the conflict?

Comment: Hmm. Try `git reset head --hard` and then `git status`

Comment: If it still not works, the final solution is just remove the current sdk folder and re-download...

Comment: ```git reset head --hard```in flutter directory and afterwards ```flutter doctor```in the project worked for me! It reinstalled the flutter sdk automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Got the Solution For

> Mac Operating System

:
Go to Your Flutter bin folder , where at 1st you had downloaded the flutter ,
then In VS Code , Open that Flutter Project ,
Get All the Package
then Open Terminal ,
Write

```
git add .
git commit -m 'problem fixed'
then from the git icon , change branch to main or master
```

that it now your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual code in Ubuntu**

```html
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD
b863200c37df4ed378042de11c4e9ff34e4e58c9
=======
2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695
>>>>>>> 27321ebbad34b0a3fafe99fac037102196d655ff...
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD
b863200c37df4ed378042de11c4e9ff34e4e58c9
=======
2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695
>>>>>>> 27321ebbad34b0a3fafe99fac037102196d655ff/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

1. Go to home.
2. select and check show hidden files.
3. find the snap and click on it.
4. delete the flutter file.
5. open the visual code run the flutter doctor in terimnal or view-->command palate..-->Run flutter doctor
6. locate the sdk are download the sdk.
7. And create a flutter project.